# javascript combining multiple regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a series of regex and jquery functions to format a textbox of 9 digits. The code looks like this:

```
function FormatBox() {

    var TheText = $('#TheBox').val();

    //remove leading 0
    if (TheText.charAt(0) === '0') {
       TheText = TheText.substring(1);   
    }

    //take only digits
    TheText = TheText.replace(/\D/g, ''); 

    //take only the first 9 digits
    if (TheText.length > 9) {
        TheText = TheText.substring(0, 9);
    }

    //reformat string
    TheText = TheText.replace(/(\d{1})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5');

    //trim string
    TheText = $.trim(TheText);

    $('#TheBox').val(TheText);
}

function Start() {

    $('#TheBox').keyup(FormatBox);
}

$(Start);
```

As it is, it all works fine but I'm looking to combine these rules that mix regex and jquery into one regex but I'm struggling to get it working. What do I need to do to add the constraints to the reformatted string to make is work? The jsFiddle is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6cZz/5/).

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `this` in `FormatBox` instead of grabbing `#TheBox` again. Also why is everything written with `LeadingCase`? This is usually a convention for naming constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
TheText = TheText.replace(/(\d{1,2})(?=(?:\d{2})+$)/g, '$1 ');
```

Comment: Ok, good start but it doesn't add the spaces at the right place and doesn't validate the length. Almost there, upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't put it all into 1 regex, but it does simplify it a bit:

```
$(Start);

function Start() {

    var box = $('#TheBox').keyup(FormatBox);

    function FormatBox() {

        box.val($.trim(box.val()
                       .replace(/(^0+|\D)/g, '') // gets rid of all leading zeros (in case of paste) and any non-numbers
                       .substring(0, 9) // or .replace(/^(.{0,9}).*/, '$1')
                       .replace(/(\d)?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?(\d{2})?/, '$1 $2 $3 $4 $5'))
               );
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the following between your `replace` clauses instead of the final `substring`: `replace(/^(.{0,9}).*/, '$1')`.  It makes little practical difference, but seems clearer to me rather than the magic number of 13.

Comment: @ScottSauyet good point. I'm not sure why I felt I needed the substring at the end